# Retrieve Ngram list with frequencies from Solr

Tags: solr, n-gram

I realised that one can get top terms from solr using following API:
    localhost:8983/solr/admin/luke?fl=text&numTerms=5000&wt=json

But this just gives a list of top unigrams (e.g."David"), NOT bigrams (e.g. "David Beckham"), trigrams etc

Is there a way I can fetch from Solr, a list of top bigrams, trigrams etc ?

Answer (score 2):

One can declare field type with the Ngram filter like:

```
<fieldType 
   name="myNGram" 
   stored="false" 
   class="solr.StrField"> 
 <analyzer type="index"> 
   <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
   <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="5"/> 
 </analyzer> 
</fieldType>
```

and then declare a copy field of type `myNGram`

```
<field name="ngrams" type="myNGram" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />

<copyField source="doc_text" dest="ngrams"/>
```

assuming that the document text is located in `doc_test` field.

```
localhost:8983/solr/admin/luke?fl=ngrams&numTerms=5000&wt=json
```

This will mix will give you the top ngrams of length 2 to 5. If you want just the bigrams you can restrict `maxGramSize` paramter of the NGramFilterFactory to 2.

Comment: Cool. Thanks! But I guess this will increase the size of index by atleast 2 times as we have now a new field "myNGram" containing data almost same in size as "docText" field, correct ?

Comment: Also it seems NGramTokenizerFactory is for splitting character wise and not word wise ?

Comment: You are absolutely right regarding the tokenizer. I have updated the answer and it also should not be a stored field if you are concerned with the space requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Ion has the right idea but you should use a [shingle filter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilterFactory.html). For example:

```
<fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="5" outputUnigrams="true"
                outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false" tokenSeparator=" "/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="ngrams" type="ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" multiValued="true" />
```

Then use the [terms component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Terms+Component) against this field:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/sample/terms?terms.fl=ngrams
```